# Why do I get "Error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory", but the file exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave to upload a file. I am trying to read from the file in Rails and any method I use to try to open it returns an error.

It returns `false` if I use:

```
File.exists(file_url)
```

If I try to use:

```
File.open(file_url, 'r'),
```

I get the error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /uploads/document/file/2/doc-sample-file.txt
from (irb):5:in `initialize'
from (irb):5:in `open'
from (irb):5
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

If I try to load a file that has been uploaded to Carrierwave in the view, like an image, there is no issue. I can also visit the file path in the browser, but the methods cannot find the path.

Comment: If `File.exists(file_url)` returns `false` that means it is __not__ in the file system.

Comment: Is there not a root path upon which CW builds the complete path?

Comment: Carrierwave root is defined this way: `"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"`
It can be accessed in the file directory and in the browser, but not by the rest of the program.

Comment: That's quite a bit different from `"/uploads.../"`. You need to prepend the Rails app's root directory to that path.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. For some reason I thought I had already tried that and had it not work. Anyway, thank you very much. If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll credit you.

Comment: *Someone* should submit an answer with the solution...